# DFS - Basic operation - remove folder target

Tags: dfs, dfs-r

I'm  new to DFS management and I need to know the proper way to delete a target(shared) folder from all the servers.

Stop replication and then delete all the copies of the folder in the different servers but does it have to be done one by one?

Comment: To be clear, are you looking to decommission DFS-R (replication) and/or DFS-N (Name) and keep the data.  Or do you want to get rid of the data as well?

Comment: hello....i just want to delete the shared folders of the users that leave the company, deleteting the entry from DFS, and also the "physical" folder from all the servers where is replicate.

Comment: do you have a DFS-R / N setup per user home drive?  if so, not the best idea IMO.  Otherwise, if it's just a folder inside a synced, folder, whack it and the changes will sync.  For example, if you have "SyncedRootFolder\User1" and "SyncedRootFolder\User2"  Deleting ".\user2" is perfectly fine and the deletion will replicated to all servers being synced.

Comment: Hello Eric, and thanks for yor time....YES we have one DFS target folder per user and per dept...so we have lots of them....really i dont know why was set up like this, but now i only need the proper way to delete both from DFS config and physically from servers. in the less steps posible

Answer (score 1):

if it was me, and I don't have DFS-R setup I would do the following:

- All from the DFS console, do the following:
- Delete the replication folder definition.  This should disable replication.
- Delete the folder under your name space.  This will disable it being in your DFS share.
- Delete the folder on each target, after 30 minutes or so.  Just to give AD replication time to kick in, and DFS timeouts to occur.  Probably overkill, but better to be safe than sorry.

**IF** you are really scared, duplicate the setup with a new name space and a new replica set and practice it.

Comment: So i understand that from DFS console there is   N O   way to eliminate the physical folders from the servers...so must be done one by one... stoping first replication, and deleting the entry under name space...right?                                                               and how about powershell...some script out there to do the mission?

Comment: That is my knowledge.  I have not used DFS-R in a LONG time, but what you stated is true for DFS-N